Definition of the Powerset axiom.
I am struggling with the power set axiom at the moment. I know what it is used for but I am having issues with the definition I got in class:
$$x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \iff x \subseteq A$$
We got the definition
$$\mathcal{P}(A) := \{x \mid x \subseteq A\}$$
while talking about Naive Set Theory (NST) earlier but it was remarked later again. So today I came to the conclusion it still holds and has nothing to do with NST because there was no remark on anything being a Naive set in that case even though a def before it was remarked.
Now a bit later I was doubting myself again and I looked up the definition online and found the following definition:
$$\forall x \, \exists y \, \forall z \, (z \in y \leftrightarrow z \subseteq x)$$
And I feel like it is similar to the first definition I got, but my problem is how can I transform the first definition I wrote down in this post into this definition I found online or is that not doable?
I had issues with the first one because of the definition for the Cartesian product because we use $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(U(x)))$
and the second one is without something is an element in Powerset...
Maybe I am misunderstanding the definition completely. So, thank you for your help and sorry for any mistakes I made, but I hope to learn from them ^^
I got the definition from this website. Set Theory - Zermelo-Fraenkel (Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Thank you, I changed the format I hope this is correct if there is more to edit, please let me know.

Please use mathjax. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation. And I guess NST means naive set theory. Since readers should mot make guesses, please explain all abbreviations you are using.

The first definition, $x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \iff x \subseteq A$ is not an axiom. It can't be, because it doesn't have any quantifiers (it's an "open" sentence) and so can't have a truth value, and it has an undefined variable $\mathcal{P}(A)$. To make it the axiom, you want to say that for every set $A$ a thing like $\mathcal{P}(A)$ exists, and that for every $x$ it obeys the rule $x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \iff x \subseteq A$.  That's exactly what your third statement says.  Note that the second definition is not allowed in ZFC because it's not stated what set $x$ must be an element of. The Axiom Schema of specification only allows you to specify subsets of already existing sets.  If the second definition sufficed, you would not need the axiom of power set.

Thank you for your answer it makes sense, also because I only read the $$x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \iff x \subseteq A$$
without reading the text I got with it, it states that the first definition defines $\mathcal{P}(A)$. I will look into it with my new insight tomorrow. Thanks again for the help I appreciate it
